# Multi-Row Headers with Flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I'm having numerous issues attempting to format my table using flextable. As an example, the below table is what I'm starting with:

```
> df
   name   x1   x2   x3   x1   x2   x3
1  <NA> 2010 2010 2010 2011 2011 2011
2 name1    1    1    1    1    1    1
3 name2    2    2    2    2    2    2
4 name3    3    3    3    3    3    3
5 name4    4    4    4    4    4    4
6 name5    5    5    5    5    5    5
```

What I'd like to do is have 2 headers - one where the year is merged for each of 3 sets of columns, and the other where the column names are the same every 3 columns. For example, I want it to look like this:

```
> df
   name x1   x2 x3 x1   x2 x3
1  <NA>    2010       2011   
2 name1  1    1  1  1    1  1
3 name2  2    2  2  2    2  2
4 name3  3    3  3  3    3  3
5 name4  4    4  4  4    4  4
6 name5  5    5  5  5    5  5
```

In addition, the year header would be above the x1,x2,x3 headers. The issue I'm having is how to designate two headers in R, and then how to merge multiple sets of 3 columns in flextable. I can merge the first set of columns (2010) using:

```
flextable(df) %>%
  merge_at(i = 1,j = c(2:4), part = "body")
```

But I am not sure how to do the above for more than one grouping. Additionally, since that row isn't designated a "header", the part that I have to designate is "body".

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend the `gt` library now for this type of formatting, would that be an option for you? https://gt.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks, yes that will most certainly be an option for me. I'll investigate it

Comment: The documentation here https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/layout.html#manage-headers-and-footers explain how to manage headers and merging cells.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I only saw the main flextable page and missed the header at the top with the detailed information. Appreciate all the work you've done on this package, it's great!

Comment: you are welcome. I think you need to separate your data from the header information, it will be far more easy

Comment: Thank you so much! My table is looking exactly how I wanted it now.

Answer (score 4):

The flextable library provides the add_header_row function for this.  With your df, the following should work.

```
    flextable(df) %>% 
      add_header_row(top = TRUE, values = c("", "2010", "2011"), colwidths = c(1,3,3))
```